# Flutter button gets enlarged onPressed()

Tags: flutter, flutter-ios-build, flutterflow

I have built a paywall component in flutterflow - But the payment button enlarges itself while loading the revenuecat subscription plans. Here is the iOS screenshot of the  [iOS button before pressed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lFNKF.jpg) and [iOS button after pressed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iwxvv.jpg)

Below is the code that I have for my widget. How can i overcome the issue?

```
import '../flutter_flow/flutter_flow_theme.dart';
import '../flutter_flow/flutter_flow_util.dart';
import '../flutter_flow/flutter_flow_widgets.dart';
import '../flutter_flow/custom_functions.dart' as functions;
import '../flutter_flow/revenue_cat_util.dart' as revenue_cat;
import 'package:auto_size_text/auto_size_text.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_spinkit/flutter_spinkit.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

import 'paywall_model.dart';
export 'paywall_model.dart';

class PaywallWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const PaywallWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _PaywallWidgetState createState() => _PaywallWidgetState();
}

class _PaywallWidgetState extends State<PaywallWidget> {
  late PaywallModel _model;

  @override
  void setState(VoidCallback callback) {
    super.setState(callback);
    _model.onUpdate();
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _model = createModel(context, () => PaywallModel());
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _model.maybeDispose();

    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    context.watch<FFAppState>();

    return ClipRRect(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(0.0),
      child: Container(
        width: double.infinity,
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 1.0,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: FlutterFlowTheme.of(context).primaryBackground,
          boxShadow: [
            BoxShadow(
              blurRadius: 4.0,
              color: Color(0x33000000),
              offset: Offset(0.0, 2.0),
            )
          ],
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(0.0),
          shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
          border: Border.all(
            color: FlutterFlowTheme.of(context).primaryBackground,
          ),
        ),
        child: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(12.0, 12.0, 12.0, 12.0),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            children: [
              Container(
                width: 500.0,
                height: 187.1,
                child: Stack(
                  children: [
                    Align(
                      alignment: AlignmentDirectional(-0.96, -0.18),
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(
                            10.0, 30.0, 10.0, 30.0),
                        child: SelectionArea(
                            child: Text(
                          revenue_cat.offerings!.current!.lifetime!.product
                              .description,
                          textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                          style: FlutterFlowTheme.of(context).bodyText2,
                        )),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Align(
                      alignment: AlignmentDirectional(-0.96, -0.85),
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(
                            10.0, 10.0, 10.0, 10.0),
                        child: SelectionArea(
                            child: AutoSizeText(
                          revenue_cat
                              .offerings!.current!.lifetime!.product.title
                              .maybeHandleOverflow(
                            maxChars: 100,
                            replacement: '…',
                          ),
                          textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                          style: FlutterFlowTheme.of(context)
                              .subtitle1
                              .override(
                                fontFamily: 'AvernirNextLTPro',
                                color: FlutterFlowTheme.of(context).primaryText,
                                useGoogleFonts: false,
                              ),
                        )),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Align(
                      alignment: AlignmentDirectional(0.0, 0.0),
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(
                            10.0, 80.0, 10.0, 0.0),
                        child: FFButtonWidget(
                          onPressed: () {
                            print('Button pressed ...');
                          },
                          text: functions.concatPriceString(revenue_cat
                              .offerings!
                              .current!
                              .lifetime!
                              .product
                              .priceString)!,
                          options: FFButtonOptions(
                            width: 300.0,
                            padding: EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(
                                0.0, 20.0, 0.0, 20.0),
                            color: Color(0xFF485946),
                            textStyle:
                                FlutterFlowTheme.of(context).subtitle2.override(
                                      fontFamily: 'AvernirNextLTPro',
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                      useGoogleFonts: false,
                                    ),
                            elevation: 2.0,
                            borderSide: BorderSide(
                              color: Colors.transparent,
                              width: 1.0,
                            ),
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: maybe set a heigh also on the `FFButtonWidget`

Comment: Thank you that worked. I used this code - options: FFButtonOptions(
                            width: 300.0,
                            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height/12